# Range validation in the Form Designer's PropertyGrid of a shadowed property

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I inherited the `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class, then I shadowed the `Form.Opacity` property.

In my scenario, the acceptable opacity value must be between **0%** and **99%**, and for this I just tried to auto-fix the provided value with a simple conditional, however, I still can set the opacity to **100%** in the designer's property grid:

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

VB.NET:

```
Public Class HUDForm : Inherits Form

    <Browsable(True)>
    <Category("Window Style")>
    <Description("The opacity level of this HUDForm.")>
    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)>
    Public Shadows Property Opacity As Double
        Get
            Return MyBase.Opacity
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            If (value >= 1.0R) Then
                value = 0.99R
            End If
            MyBase.Opacity = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

C# (online translation):

```
public class HUDForm : Form {

    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Window Style")]
    [Description("The opacity level of this HUDForm.")]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    public new double Opacity {
        get { return base.Opacity; }
        set {
            if (value >= 1.0) {
                value = 0.99;
            }
            base.Opacity = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It works fine, the sample form needs a constructor so the default value (100%) is no longer out of range.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks for comment and for your interest on this noob question of mine. Yes of course I'm aware of what you said, at runtime the value will be validated/fixed properly, but you know, it could be much prettier if the validation could be made when building the UI when setting the value in the Property Grid. I am a kind of perfectionism maniac that tries to cover this kind of minimal details (that in no case can be the same as being perfect, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Form`'s designer is the controlling factor as it is handling the validation of the Opacity property as well as several other properties.  You will need to create a custom [DocumentDesigner Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.documentdesigner%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and set the [DesignerAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) on your HUDForm Class.  For the official word on extending design time support, see: [Extending Design-Time Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37899azc(v=vs.110).aspx).

The class `System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner` is the specified designer for the `Form` class.  This designer is inherited when your class inherits from the `Form` class. `FormDocumentDesigner` ultimately inherits from  [ComponentDesigner Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.componentdesigner(v=vs.110).aspx).  A designer may provide alternate property implementations that are in effect during design.  It does so by modifying the PropertyDescriptors that are sent to the VS designer's propertygrid.  This modification is done in the `PreFilterProperties` method.  In this case, alternate property definitions are provide for the Opacity, Menu, IsMdiContainer, Size, ShowInTaskBar, WindowState, AutoSize, AcceptButton, and and CancelButton properties.

As you can not inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner`, you would need to re-implement this class with your desired function.

Here is a very abbreviated custom DocumentDesigner that will provide the specific functionality you want only for demonstration of the technique.  You will need to re-implement the reset of the function provided by the `System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner` class.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class myDocDesigner
  Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Design.DocumentDesigner

    Private Property Opacity As Double
        Get
                Return CDbl(MyBase.ShadowProperties.Item("Opacity"))
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
        If (value >= 0.99R) Then
                value = 0.99R
        End If

                MyBase.ShadowProperties.Item("Opacity") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub PreFilterProperties(ByVal properties As IDictionary)
        Dim descriptor As PropertyDescriptor
        MyBase.PreFilterProperties(properties)
        Dim strArray As String() = New String() {"Opacity"}
        Dim attributes As Attribute() = {}
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To strArray.Length - 1
                descriptor = DirectCast(properties.Item(strArray(i)), PropertyDescriptor)
                If (Not descriptor Is Nothing) Then
                    properties.Item(strArray(i)) = TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty(GetType(myDocDesigner), descriptor, attributes)
                End If
        Next i
    End Sub
End Class
```

You would decorate your custom form like this:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.Design

<Designer(GetType(myDocDesigner), GetType(IRootDesigner))>
Public Class HUDForm : Inherits Form

End Class
```

You will need a project reference to `System.Design.dll`.

---

Alternate Solution

After thinking this over a bit more, I realized that the OP's constraint is more restrictive of the value than that coded in `FormDocumentDesigner`, yet still satisfies those constraints.  The default Opacity property has multiple checks on its allowed range.  The simplest one to override is the TypeConverter applied to the property.  The base implementation uses the [OpacityConverter Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.opacityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and the following TypeConverter is derived from that implementation.

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class OpacityConverter2
     Inherits TypeConverter
     Public Overrides Function CanConvertFrom(ByVal context As ITypeDescriptorContext, ByVal sourceType As Type) As Boolean
          Return ((sourceType Is GetType(String)) OrElse MyBase.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType))
     End Function

     Public Overrides Function ConvertFrom(ByVal context As ITypeDescriptorContext, ByVal culture As CultureInfo, ByVal value As Object) As Object
          If Not TypeOf value Is String Then
                Return MyBase.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value)
          End If
          Dim currentValueAsString As String = CStr(value).Replace("%"c, " "c).Trim
          Dim parsedValue As Double = Double.Parse(currentValueAsString, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
          If (((CStr(value).IndexOf("%") > 0) AndAlso (parsedValue >= 0)) AndAlso (parsedValue <= 1)) Then
                currentValueAsString = (parsedValue / 100).ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
          End If
          Dim returnValue As Double = 0
          Try
                returnValue = CDbl(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(Double)).ConvertFrom(context, culture, currentValueAsString))
                If (returnValue > 1) Then
                     returnValue = (returnValue / 100)
                End If
          Catch exception As FormatException
                Throw New FormatException("Valid Range - 0 to 99%", exception)
          End Try
          If ((returnValue >= 0) AndAlso (returnValue <= 0.99)) Then
                Return returnValue
          Else
              Throw New FormatException("Valid Range - 0 to 99%")
          End If
     End Function

     Public Overrides Function ConvertTo(ByVal context As ITypeDescriptorContext, ByVal culture As CultureInfo, ByVal value As Object, ByVal destinationType As Type) As Object
          If (destinationType Is Nothing) Then
                Throw New ArgumentNullException("destinationType")
          End If
          If (destinationType Is GetType(String)) Then
                Dim num As Double = CDbl(value)
                Dim num2 As Integer = CInt((num * 100))
                Return (num2.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) & "%")
          End If
          Return MyBase.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType)
     End Function

End Class
```

Usage:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.Design

Public Class HUDForm : Inherits Form

    <TypeConverter(GetType(OpacityConverter2))>
     <Browsable(True)>
     <Category("Window Style")>
     <Description("The opacity level of this HUDForm.")>
     <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)>
     Public Shadows Property Opacity As Double
          Get
                Return MyBase.Opacity
          End Get
          Set(ByVal value As Double)
                If (value >= 1.0R) Then
                     value = 0.99R
                End If
                MyBase.Opacity = value
          End Set
     End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for answer,but then if I understood this solution implies to lose all the other default validations that are done on all the other default properties?,then more than a solution it could be a hardcoded patch to solve a single thing and damage multiple others, because it will generate me more problems to resolve,like for example starting to decompile or better said reconstruct almost from zero all the content/validations of the default `System.Windows.Forms.Design.DocumentDesigner` class?...I apologize but I think this proposal wouldn't be the best solution.Maybe exists other alternative?

Comment: @ElektroStudios, check out the current proposed alternative.

Comment: The provided alternative seems a nice,very smart,and reusable piece of code,seems it will not have downsides like the first solution.Thanks a lot for your time,your patience and for sharing this,¡good job!, however to finally end and accept this answer please could you say how I could reproduce the same behavior than the default control used for the Form.Opacity property?, at first sight it seems a textbox, it is?, the problem would be the validation and the "%" char (I just ask for your oppinion, a brief suggestion, I dont want to make you work more adapting the solution that you've provided)

Comment: @ElektroStudios, I'm not clear on what you are asking.  What do you mean by "how I could reproduce the same behavior than the default control used for the Form.Opacity property?"?  As far as I'm concerned, the alternative is the same as the Form.Opacity implementation except for the displayed error message.

Comment: Sorry for my English. I mean that in the default implementation for the Opacity property it is used a textbox with an acceptable range of "0%" to "100%",while in your solution you used a numericupdown with an acceptable range from "0.0" to "0.999999999999...+", those are the values that the user can write in the numericupdown,so,since in the default textbox the user only needs to put a value of 0 to 100 is more friendly,that is what I mean,then I would like to replace the numericupdown for a textbox to mimic the normal behavior for this kind of value,and I only ask for suggestions to do so.

Comment: @ElektroStudios, lol.  We have a timing issue here as you are looking at Alt#1 and I'm talking about Alt#2.  I deleted the NumericUpDown solution and replaced it with a TypeConverter based solution.  It has been several years since I've done this stuff and it took a while for me to think straight and thoroughly inspect how the default was being handled.  Try the current alternative, it should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh, and talking about the exception message, for those who are interested in your solution and are wondering how to do that, I just did it in the setter block of the property: `If (Me.DesignMode) AndAlso (value >= MAXIMUM) Then Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", "Error message here...")` I firstly tried to throw the same exception inside the TypeConverter class but then it will not show any exception on the propertygrid, so this seems the way to go, or at least it works as expected.

Comment: I am very sorry didn't noted the last update 40 mins ago, I thinked you were talking about the first-second alternative. You even covered the exception message personalization and everything what I were talking about the range of 0% to 100%, it is fantastic, thanks a lot mate!.